# Xamarin NuGet package error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services, nuget-package

I'm trying to use material theme and add ads for my android app.

I can't install `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` package with `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads` The error message tells me that a package is trying to rollback another package.

I have asked this question on Xamarin forum, but it seems like no one was interested in this issue.

> [AppName] (>= 1.0.0) -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (>= 25.3.1) ->
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 25.3.1)
>
> [AppName](>= 1.0.0) -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads (>= 42.1021.1)
>   -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (>= 42.1021.1) -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (>= 25.1.0) ->
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 25.1.0).

Comment: Don't say no one was interested... What's the order you are following to install the packages? Ads first or Support.Design ?

Comment: Support.Design was first.

Comment: After the installation fails, what text is in the "Output"?

Comment: Using Xamarin.Studio on Mac File -> new Xamarin.Android project. Installed package `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` then `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads` and the installation succeed... as Sean said => What's the output of your installation. It usually gives a detailed error while the rollback.

Comment: The console basocally says a package os trying to rollback existing package.

Comment: @schmzmtl copy and paste the whole console output in the original post. You might be missing something.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't written in English, so I can't just copy and paste. But, I can fully translate it, in which the outcome might not be in exact words, after finishing the Visual Studio Update.

Comment: I think you have a versioning problem. Try uninstalling all google play / support / design packages etc. and reinstall starting with google play (they will add their dependencies) then install any missing (what language is your output in - there are plenty of nationalities on stackoverflow - maybe someone just understands it and can help)

Comment: Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat에 대한 버전 충돌이 검색되었습니다. 
 [AppName] (>= 1.0.0) -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (>= 25.3.1) -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 25.3.1) 
 [AppName] (>= 1.0.0) -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads (>= 42.1021.1) -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (>= 42.1021.1) -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (>= 25.1.0) -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 25.1.0).
패키지 복원에 실패했습니다. 'Gamgeum'에 대한 패키지 변경 내용을 롤백하고 있습니다.

Comment: Maybe Google translator can help.

Comment: Also tried to install it on a new project, but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Solved it by installing `Xamarin.Android.Support.V4`.

`Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement` uses `Xamarin.Android.Support.V4`, so I wondered what would happen if I install `Xamarin.Android.Support.V4`.

But I am not really sure how someone in the comment was able to install `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads` without installing `Xamarin.Android.Support.V4`.

== EDIT ==

Visual Studio 2017 Version was 15.2 (26430.13)

== EDIT ==

It seems like other problems with Xamarin sometimes has to do with SDK manager. I had another problem with NuGet package. In this problem, a NuGet package couldn't be installed because the monoandroid version wasn't supported. This issue was fixed by installing few Android version specific packages in the SDK manager. This problem has nothing to do with this issue, but just in case if someone needs it. The other answer blow is similar to this.

Comment: Nice you were able to fix it! Xamarin.Andorid.Support.V4 is part of the new template when you create a brand new Xamarin.Android project with Xamarin.Studio. So when creating a new project you don't need to install it. Would be nice to know which version of XS or VS you were using.

Answer (score 1):

To Fix you problem - your app needs to have its **Target Framework set to Android 7.0** (API Level 24) or higher to install it.

You can change it in **Project Options -> General -> Target Framework**.